# LINQ to Entities returning "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a piece of code that checks to see if a user is in our database using a view called `RESOURCE_V`. If not, the code uses Entity Framework to add the user to the database using the user's information from Active Directory. I would then like to re-query the `RESOURCE_V` view to get the submitted information. Upon doing so I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". Here is the full code:

```
HALEntities context = new HALEntities();
            List<RESOURCE_V> userData = (from i in context.RESOURCE_V
                                         where i.NT_USER_N == Environment.UserName
                                         select i).ToList();

            // add user to RSRC table using Active Directory details
            if (userData.Count > 0)
            {
                PrincipalContext principleContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, HAL_Globals.domain);
                UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principleContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, HAL_Globals.domain + "\\" + Environment.UserName);
                RSRC rsrc = new RSRC();

                rsrc.RSRC_I = context.RSRCs.Select(u => u.RSRC_I).Max() + 1;
                rsrc.NT_USER_N = user.SamAccountName + "AAAA";
                rsrc.FRST_N = user.GivenName;
                rsrc.LAST_N = user.Surname;
                rsrc.INIL_N = (user.MiddleName == null) ? "X" : user.MiddleName.Substring(0, 1);
                rsrc.SHRT_N = user.GivenName.Substring(0, 1) + ((user.MiddleName == null) ? "X" : user.MiddleName.Substring(0, 1)) + user.Surname.Substring(0, 1);
                rsrc.EMAIL_I = user.EmailAddress;
                rsrc.TELE_I = user.VoiceTelephoneNumber.Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace("-", "");
                rsrc.ACTV_F = true;
                rsrc.CRTE_USER_I = Environment.UserName;
                rsrc.CRTE_TS = DateTime.Now;
                rsrc.UPDT_USER_I = Environment.UserName;
                rsrc.UPDT_TS = DateTime.Now;

                context.RSRCs.Add(rsrc);
                context.SaveChanges();
                userData = (from i in context.RESOURCE_V
                            where i.NT_USER_N == Environment.UserName + "AAAA"
                            select i).ToList();
            }
```

Notice the logic doesn't exactly match my description as I am using this code to test against my ID that already exists. The line that errors out is the very last statement in the `if` block:

```
userData = (from i in context.RESOURCE_V
                            where i.NT_USER_N == Environment.UserName + "AAAA"
                            select i).ToList();
```

I have tried recreating the Entity context, using different LINQ syntax, but have had no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

As requested, here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstanceCritical(Type type, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.SafeReflectionInvoker.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Xaml.Schema.XamlTypeInvoker.CreateInstance(Object[] arguments)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstanceWithCtor(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.PartialTrustTolerantRuntime.CreateInstance(XamlType xamlType, Object[] args)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
   at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember property)
   at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.TransformNodes(XamlReader xamlReader, XamlObjectWriter xamlWriter, Boolean onlyLoadOneNode, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Boolean shouldPassLineNumberInfo, IXamlLineInfo xamlLineInfo, IXamlLineInfoConsumer xamlLineInfoConsumer, XamlContextStack`1 stack, IStyleConnector styleConnector)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadBamlStreamWithSyncInfo(Stream stream, ParserContext pc)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Uri resourceLocator, Boolean bSkipJournaledProperties)
   at System.Windows.Application.DoStartup()
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at HAL.App.Main() in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Edit 2: The Inner Exception Stack Trace:

```
at System.Data.EntityKey.AddHashValue(Int32 hashCode, Object keyValue)
   at System.Data.EntityKey.GetHashCode()
   at System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1.GetHashCode(T obj)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectStateManager.TryGetEntityEntry(EntityKey key, EntityEntry& entry)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper )
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper)
   at System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at HAL.HAL_CurrentUser..ctor(SqlConnection currentServerConnection) in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\Global Classes\HAL_CurrentUser.cs:line 86
   at HAL.HAL_CurrentUser.get_Instance() in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\Global Classes\HAL_CurrentUser.cs:line 46
   at HAL.WelcomeViewModel..ctor() in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\HAL Classes\Welcome\WelcomeViewModel.cs:line 21
   at HAL.Welcome..ctor() in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\HAL Classes\Welcome\Welcome.xaml.cs:line 26
   at HAL.Navigation..ctor() in c:\HAL\HAL_PROD\HAL\Navigation.xaml.cs:line 17
```

Edit 3:

After playing around with the values being queried in the second LINQ query I have determined the issue is being caused by the fact that I am filtering on the new ID in the where clause of the LINQ query. If I hard-code another ID in the query it works and the error is not thrown. I have determined the new ID is in fact being added to the database.

Comment: `content`, `Resource_V`, or `i` is null

Comment: wouldn't you want `if (userData.Count == 0)` and not `if (userData.Count > 0)`?

Comment: @hunter Yes, like I said the code doesn't match my description because I am testing against an existing ID. Thanks though!

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: I believe it cannot execute the `ToList()` statement, probably there's something wrong with the query, especially with the view

Comment: @Sayse: If `context.RESOURCE_V` is an EntityFramework collection, then this will be evaluated by Entity Framework, so `i` cannot be null`. And since he uses `context.RESOURCE_V` prior to this point, clearly that is not null.

Comment: please double check the line that is throwing. Seems unlikely that re-querying like you are would throw the 2nd time and not the first.

Comment: @KirkWoll I added the stack trace as requested. Thanks!

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - I take your point about `i` but we don't know enough about `SaveChanges` to guarrantee that `Resource_V` isn't null

Comment: @user3043546, the NRE does not happen in your code.  Presumably you are passing a null value of some sort to a WPF control that does not handle such a value very gracefully. Unfortunately I've never used WPF so can provide no guidance.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior What else is there to know about `SaveChanges()`? Honest question, I'd be glad to provide more information.

Comment: What version of EF and are you using ObjectContext or DBContext?

Comment: @Gratzy Version 5.0.0 and we are using `DBContext`.

Comment: @KirkWoll Thanks for the information. Where are you seeing it is a WPF related issue? The stack trace looks like a mess to me. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen all of the time?  Is this potentially a threading issue?

Comment: @user3043546, I see lots of `WpfXXX` and `XamlXXX` identifiers in there, both of which imply WPF.

Comment: @Gratzy Yes this happens every time I run the application. My application is mostly a single threaded application so that doesn't stick out to me as a potential problem. Maybe though?

Comment: @KirkWoll OK I see. I thought you meant a specific line of the trace. Thanks!

Comment: There is no EF in this stacktrace. If the issue is caused by EF you need to show InnerExceptions if any.

Comment: @Sayse: The Entity Framework code is open-sourced, so you can check if you want, but I think it's safe to say that `SaveChanges()` will never  go and set the context's properties to null.

Comment: @Pawel I have added the inner exception trace. Thanks!

Comment: When you append the "AAAA" to the id is the id chopped i.e. the appended id is longer than the column size in the database and therefore the database returns a different key? (e.g. the size of the column is 4 your original id is 'abc' but after appending it is 'abcAAAA' when you insert only 'abcA' gets inserted)?

Comment: I think your entity has a composite key and when you save the entity the other part of the key is not set and therefore is null. When reading this entity EF fails because it does not expect any part of the key to be set to null. Probably a bug in EF if it allowed you to save a null value to a key column (unless there is some mismatch in your model).

Comment: @Pawel You're absolutely right! The view I am reading has an entity key on two fields that are coming in as NULL. These should be nullable because they are the result of a left join. Should I just remove these as entity keys on the view using the Entity Framework designer? **Edit**: Yes this was the solution. Please add your comment as an answer, I will mark it appropriately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entity has a composite key and when you save the new entity one of the key column is null. EF does not support nullable keys (it throws) but apparently there is a bug in EF where this condition is not checked in this specific scenario and hence the NRE. You need to make sure that you are not returning null values in primary key columns.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My class field of collection type was empty. I struggled a lot to fix the problem. 
Finally the error was in typo - I was creating the object with `new` while making local declaration for the class field name and then it was going out of local scope.
I know that it doesn't answer the topic, but as a point to re-check the code for such errors. 
Sorry, I really wanted to help other guys like me with the similar problem.